Kubernetes create cluster multimaster using bitnami/mariadb-galera
I'm trying to deploy mariadb-galera multimaster on kubernetes. But when I set external volume I receive this error:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied

this is my yaml:
# PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: datadir-galera-0
  namespace: mon-zabbix
  labels:
    app: galera-ss
    podindex: "0"
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /var/openebs/galera-0/datadir
---
# Persistent Volumes Claim
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-datadir-galera-ss-0
  namespace: mon-zabbix
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: galera-ss
      podindex: "0"
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: galera-ss
  namespace: mon-zabbix
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  selector:
    app: galera-ss
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: galera-ss
  namespace: mon-zabbix
spec:
  serviceName: galera-ss
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: galera-ss
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: galera-ss
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: galera
        image: bitnami/mariadb-galera:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: secrets
                key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_NAME
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: CLUSTER_NAME
                name: configmap
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_BOOTSTRAP
          value: "yes"
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_NODE_ADDRESS
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_ADDRESS
          value: "galera-ss.default.svc.cluster.local"
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_MARIABACKUP_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: secrets
                key: XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-datadir
          mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mysql-datadir
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi

I tried to fix using the solutions find in other posts but it doesn't works for me. I'm using talos to create the kubernetes cluster (v1.28.0)
Could someone show how can I fix it, please?

I solved using initContainers:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: galera-ss
  namespace: mon-grafana
spec:
  serviceName: galera-ss
  replicas: 1             # run only 1 to initialize cluster
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: galera-ss
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: galera-ss
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: volume-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: [ "sh", "-c", "chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami/mariadb && chmod -R 775 /bitnami/mariadb" ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvc-grafana-mariadb
          mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
      containers:
      - name: galera
        image: bitnami/mariadb-galera:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_FORCE_SAFETOBOOTSTRAP
          value: "yes"
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_BOOTSTRAP
          value: "yes"
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_ADDRESS
          value: "gcomm://galera-ss:4567"
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                name: secrets
        - name: MARIADB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_PASSWORD
                name: secrets
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_MARIABACKUP_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD
                name: secrets
        - name: MARIADB_USER
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_USER
                name: configmap
        - name: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_NAME
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_GALERA_CLUSTER_NAME
                name: configmap        
        - name: MARIADB_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_DATABASE
                name: configmap
        - name: MARIADB_DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET
                name: configmap
        - name: MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET
                name: configmap
        - name: MARIADB_COLLATE
          valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: MARIADB_COLLATE
                name: configmap
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvc-grafana-mariadb
          mountPath: /bitnami/mariadb
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
      restartPolicy: Always
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: pvc-grafana-mariadb
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi


Secret object is missing. Please also post secret yaml and other config files
